# Creating Connections between Elements in jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, draggable, droppable, jsplumb, connection

I have created a simple UI where a user can drag elements from the toolbox and drop them on the canvas and then connect them with each other. But when I try to make the connections after giving each the connection points(the white square on the elements' left corner), unique IDs, the connecting lines start from somewhere else in the canvas and do not get connected as shown below.As soon as I release the mouse the connector lines disappear.

[image: wrong connections]

Here's my JS Function where I drop the element

```
function dropCompleteElement(newAgent,i,e,kind)
    {
        $(droppedElement).draggable({containment: "container"});

        var finalElement =  newAgent;
        r++; q++;

        if(kind=="import")
        {
            var connection = $('<div>').attr('id', i + '-import').addClass('connection');
        }
        else if (kind=="export")
        {
            var connection = $('<div>').attr('id', i + '-export').addClass('connection');
        }
        else
        {
            var connection = $('<div>').attr('id', i + '-defined').addClass('connection');
        }


        finalElement.css({
            'top': e.pageY,
            'left': e.pageX
        });


        finalElement.append(connection);

        $('#container').append(finalElement);

        jsPlumb.draggable(finalElement, {
            containment: 'parent'
        });

        jsPlumb.makeTarget(connection, {
            anchor: 'Continuous'
        });

        jsPlumb.makeSource(connection, {
            anchor: 'Continuous'
        });

        $("#container").removeClass("disabledbutton");
        $("#toolbox").removeClass("disabledbutton");

        var myNode = document.getElementById("lot");
        var fc = myNode.firstChild;

        while( fc ) {
            myNode.removeChild( fc );
            fc = myNode.firstChild;
        }

        $(".toolbox-titlex").hide();
        $(".panel").hide();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple change to the CSS relating to the dropped element made all the difference. But am trying to figure out how exactly this change affected the behaviour of the connectors as am simply appending them to the already existing jsPlumb drop element. So far my best guess is the z-index property. So I thought of sharing this here and would encourage further answers in this regard as well.

**CSS**

```
.streamdrop {
    border: 1px solid #346789;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;
    -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 130px;
    height: 72px;
    line-height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #eeeeef;
    color: black;
    font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0.5em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: -moz-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in;
    -o-transition: -o-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in;
    transition: box-shadow 0.15s ease-in;
}
```